# Opening word document with read mode using python

Tags: python, ms-word

I have a python applicaiton that need to luanch a word document .
is there any option to luanch a word document with read mode only from python ?

Comment: @Matt - OP wants to launch Word in read-only mode. If there is any option to launch Word in read-only mode from commandline, then it is possible to do so from Python too.

Comment: @eumiro - oh! That wasn't at all clear to me, but sounds reasonable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find some very useful samples on the following page:

> **[Python for Windows: Microsoft Office](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/category/7/86/192/)**

Opening a Word document read-only [can be achieved](http://win32com.goermezer.de/content/view/94/192/) like this, `True` as the third parameter to [`Application.Documents.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216319%28office.12%29.aspx) tells Word to open the document read-only.

```
import win32com.client, pythoncom, time

def word(wordfile):
    pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)
    myWord = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Word.Application')
    myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(wordfile, False, False, True)

    ...

    myDoc.Close()
    myWord.Quit()
    del myDoc
    del myWord
    pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Comment: It really help but do you know why this is works only from the second calling to the function word ?

Comment: @AKM: What happens the first time?

Comment: It do nothing but I see a Winword application running on the task Manager

Comment: @AKM: Try to find out, whether the line that opens the document is actually reached the first time and try stepping through the code.

Comment: As per the cited manual, the prototype for this leads: "expression.Open(FileName, ConfirmConversions, ReadOnly,"... So, for ReadOnly, you'd want the third parameter as True, not False as stated. Also, really, keyword parameter would be more explicit and only tweak the features being discussed so, perhaps:  `myDoc = myWord.Documents.Open(FileName=wordfile, ReadOnly=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You could always fire up the msword from command line via the command (Check the path)

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Winword.exe /f <filename>
```

I am assuming you want to launch msword and not read word docs programmatically.
To be able to do that from python, you need to use the facility to run external commands.

see : http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system

```
import os
os.system(command)
```

or:

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.call(command)
```

See the various command line options at:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565

Comment: this really help but winword.exe is founded under officexx that means my python application will not work under some officexx that different from the oficeYY which found on my pc

Comment: @AKM: winword.exe is usually on the path so just try using winword.exe without the path.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @pyfunc. Just a small suggestion. When you have spaces in paths , sometimes it doesn't work . So you need to mention it like this:

```
 C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft Office 2013"\Office15\WINWORD.exe D:\inchowar\Desktop\Junk.docx
```